# Maximum number of points in convex position on a grid

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Guys this problem really bothers me (I don`t know how to prove it) please help:

What is the maximum number of points in convex position on a $n\times m$ grid?

(My guess would be $2*(m+n)-4$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. There are at most two vertical sections which contain more than 2 points. So, totally we have at most $m+m+(n-2)2=2m+2n-4$ points. The example is the perimeter of the grid.

Comment: oh yes right, thank you very much ....

Comment: i am thinking now what would happen if we consider the grid made of two sets of concentric circles instead of lines ?!

Comment: Dear Petrov , as you have a clear vision about this question , may i please ask for your opinion about the circle case : maximum number of points in convex position on a grid made by two sets of concentric circle , one set m circle and another n circles ?.....thank you very much

Comment: I do not know immediately, this looks a solvable, but not trivial problem. I recommend to post it in a separate MO question.